# getting "CleverTap error: 512: VIEWED_CART event structure invalid. Not sent" error while passing data which has nested arrays for Custom Events

Tags: reactjs, next.js, clevertap

I'm trying to trigger a Clevertap custom event called "VIEWED CART". Whenever my payload data having nested array or object the event is not triggering. I'm getting error like "CleverTap [1691648406753]: CleverTap error: 512: VIEWED_CART event structure invalid. Not sent".
If I remove this inner/nested array the clevertap event triggering successfully.

This is the data I'm trying to pass to Clevetap.

```
"evtData": {
        "Platform": "MWEB",
        "Store": "UAE",
        "Currency": "AED",
        "purchaseItems": [
            {
                "itemName": "Product A",
                "itemCategory": "Electronics",
                "itemPrice": 249.99
            },
            {
                "itemName": "Product B",
                "itemCategory": "Clothing",
                "itemPrice": 99.99
            },
            {
                "itemName": "Product C",
                "itemCategory": "Books",
                "itemPrice": 19.99
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Facing the same issue, were you able to find a solution?